# How to show Div or Iframe on top of all the web pages?

Tags: html, iframe

I have 5 web pages in my website, **I want to show one div or Iframe on top of all the web pages in Bottom Right corner...Like Chat window.**

**so where should I add div/iframe so that it will accessible to all the page as top window.**

**example-**
https://www.livechatinc.com/

I am able to do this for one web page but when I am navigating to another page then div is hiding.

Please suggest the possible solution.

Answer (score 5):

Hi you can use the following html -

```
<div class="chat-box"><a href="#" class="chat-bubble"></a></div>

<style>
.chat-box {
    white-space: pre;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 100; 
    bottom: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
}
.chat-bubble {
    box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .14), 0 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .28);
    background-size: 22px 22px;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 0;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 48px;
    height: 48px;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
    background-position: center;
    background-color: #0071b2;
    -webkit-user-drag: none;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1) rotate(360deg);
    transform: scale(1) rotate(360deg);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 150ms cubic-bezier(.4, 0, 1, 1);
    transition: transform 150ms cubic-bezier(.4, 0, 1, 1);
}

</style>
```

Above sample is for chat bubble, you can modify the style according to your requirement.

You can also add chat icon inside chat bubble as we did in [Applozic chat plugin](https://github.com/AppLozic/Applozic-Web-Plugin).

Answer (score 0):

> I am able to do this for one web page but when I am navigating to another page then div is hiding.

Call the function which shows the chat bar in the first page on every page refresh

Comment: Hi, in this case every time div/iframe content will be loaded and it will not maintain the previous data.

Comment: You can store the data in localstorage / session cookies / session storage - there are lot of options

Comment: first tell me where should I define div/iframe tag so that it is accessible to all the page?

Comment: check this example-